rust display a window using the windows crate
In my rust experiments I'm currently trying the following. I want to display a basic empty window using the windows crate and the windows API. The below code compiles and executes. The only thing it does not do is display an actual window. What am I doing wrong here as the code looks find to me and the e.g. c++ equivalent would show a window I believe.

use windows::{
    core::*, Win32::{Foundation::*, Graphics::Gdi::{CreateSolidBrush, UpdateWindow, ValidateRect, COLOR_WINDOW, HBRUSH}, System::LibraryLoader::{GetModuleHandleA, GetModuleHandleW}, UI::WindowsAndMessaging::*},
};
fn main() -> Result<()> {
    
    

    unsafe{
        let window_class = w!("the_window");
        let window_name = w!("The Factory");
        let instance = GetModuleHandleW(None)?;
        let kleur = COLORREF{
            0: 255,
        };
        let brush: HBRUSH = CreateSolidBrush(kleur);
        debug_assert!(instance.0 != 0);

        //define the window
        let wc = WNDCLASSW {
            hCursor: LoadCursorW(None, IDC_ARROW)?,
            style: CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW,
            lpszClassName: window_name,
            hInstance: instance.into(),
            hbrBackground: brush,
            lpfnWndProc: Some(wndproc),
            ..Default::default()
        };

        //register the class
        let atom = RegisterClassW(&wc);
        debug_assert!(atom != 0);
        let hwnd_desktop = GetDesktopWindow();

        let hwnd = CreateWindowExW(WINDOW_EX_STYLE::default(), window_class, window_name, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 100, 100, 100, 100, hwnd_desktop, None, instance, None);
        
        
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);

        let mut message = std::mem::zeroed();
        println!("init the msg structure success.");

        while GetMessageA(&mut message, None, 0, 0).into() {
            TranslateMessage(&message);
            DispatchMessageA(&message);
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    
}

extern "system" fn wndproc(window: HWND, message: u32, wparam: WPARAM, lparam: LPARAM) -> LRESULT {
    unsafe {
        match message {
            WM_PAINT => {
                println!("WM_PAINT");
                _ = ValidateRect(window, None);
                LRESULT(0)
            }
            WM_DESTROY => {
                println!("WM_DESTROY");
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                LRESULT(0)
            }
            _ => DefWindowProcA(window, message, wparam, lparam),
        }
    }
}


The equivalent C++ code fails for the same reason as this code: An attempt to create a window of a class that has not been registered.
The specific issue is here:
let wc = WNDCLASSW {
    // ...
    lpszClassName: window_name,
    // ...
    ..Default::default()
};

This prepares a WNDCLASSW structure to be registered under the name window_name. The subsequent call to CreateWindowExW() then requests a window of class window_class to be created (which hasn't been registered).
Before moving ahead to address the issue let's appreciate the fact that CreateWindowExW() can fail and add the following error handling code:
let hwnd = CreateWindowExW(
    // ...
);

if hwnd == HWND::default() {
    return Err(Error::from_win32());
}

With that in place, the program now terminates. Issuing cargo run produces (among others) the following output:
Error: Error { code: HRESULT(0x8007057F), message: "Cannot find window class." }

That's helpful and confirms the suspicion of a mismatch between registered and requested class names.
The fix is simple: Ensure that registered and requested class names agree. Updating the WNDCLASSW initialization to read
let wc = WNDCLASSW {
    // ...
    lpszClassName: window_class,
    // ...
    ..Default::default()
};

gets you

Done!

Until you grab the right edge and move it further to the right. Just enough to leave no doubt that something doesn't display as intended. Something like

The window title should read The Factory but the display says T. This is another incarnation of The program “G” is preventing you from shutting down.
In a nutshell: The encoding variant used for class registration (RegisterClassA or RegisterClassW) MUST agree with the encoding assumed by the provided window procedure. The most prominent example is delegation of unhandled messages:
The window procedure of a class registered with

RegisterClassA must delegate to DefWindowProcA
RegisterClassW must delegate to DefWindowProcW

The code in question registers the window class using RegisterClassW but delegates to DefWindowProcA, causing (among other issues) the truncation of the displayed window title.
The fix here is equally simple:
_ => DefWindowProcW(window, message, wparam, lparam),

which produces this window


can't believe I did not spot that mistake (the class registration). The other issue remains as I switched from RegisterClassA to RegisterClassW to see if that would make a difference. Anhyhow it works. Big Thank You!
